# Implementing rental store in Rails: how to track an inventory state over time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, tracking, temporal

Let's say you're implementing rails app for a snowboard rental store.

A given snowboard can be in one of 3 states:

1. away for maintenance
2. available at store X
3. on loan to customer Y

The company needs to be able to view a rental history for

- a particular snowboard
- a particular customer

The rental history needs to include temporal data (e.g. Sally rented snowboard 0123 from Dec. 1, 2009 to Dec. 3 2009).

How would you design your model? Would you have a snowboard table with 4 columns (id, state, customer, store), and copy rows from this table, along with a timestamp, to a snowboard_history table every time the state changes?

Thanks!

(Note: I'm not actually trying to implement a rental store; this was just the simplest analogue I could think of.)

Comment: I was thinking about using ActiveRecord::Observer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use a pair of plugins to get the job done. Which would use four models. Snowboard, Store, User and Audit.

[acts_as_state_machine](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm) and [acts_as_audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited)

AASM simplifies the state transitions. While auditing creates the history you want.

The code for Store and User is trivial and acts_as_audited will handle the audits model.

```
class Snowboard < ActiveRecord::Base

  include AASM
  belongs_to :store
  

  aasm_initial_state :unread
  acts_as_audited :only => :state

  aasm_state :maintenance
  aasm_state :available
  aasm_state :rented

  aasm_event :send_for_repairs do
    transitions :to => :maintenance, :from => [:available]
  end

  aasm_event :return_from_repairs do
    transitions :to => :available, :from => [:maintenance]
  end

  aasm_event :rent_to_customer do
   transitions :to => :rented, :from => [:available]
  end

  aasm_event :returned_by_customer do
    transitions :to => :available, :from => [:rented]
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :full_history, :class_name => 'Audit', :as => :user,
   :conditions => {:auditable_type => "Snowboard"}
end
```

Assuming your customer is the current_user during the controller action when state changes that's all you need.

To get a snowboard history:

```
@snowboard.audits
```

To get a customer's rental history:

```
@customer.full_history
```

You might want to create a helper method to shape a customer's history into something more useful. Maybe something like his:

```
 def rental_history
    history = []
    outstanding_rentals = {}
    full_history.each do |item|
      id = item.auditable_id
      if rented_at = outstanding_rentals.keys.delete(id)
        history << { 
          :snowboard_id => id, 
          :rental_start => rented_at,
          :rental_end => item.created_at
        }   
      else
        outstanding_rentals[:id] = item.created_at
      end
    end
    history << oustanding_rentals.collect{|key, value| {:snowboard_id => key,  
      :rental_start => value}
  end
end
```

Comment: Damn that's elegant! Thanks so much EmFi :D

Comment: Odds are some one has tackled a similar problem and made it a gem/plugin. The only problem is finding out about existing gems/plugins.

Answer (score 2):

First I would generate separate models for Snowboard, Customer and Store.

```
script/generate model Snowboard name:string price:integer ...
script/generate model Customer name:string ...
script/generate model Store name:string ...
```

(rails automatically generates `id` and `created_at`, `modified_at` dates)

To preserve the history, I wouldn't copy rows/values from those tables, unless it is necessary (for example if you'd like to track the price customer rented it).

Instead, I would create SnowboardEvent model (you could call it `SnowboardHistory` if you like, but personally it feels strange to make new history) with the similiar properties you described:

- `ev_type` (ie. 0 for RETURN, 1 for MAINTENANCE, 2 for RENT...)
- `snowboard_id` (not null)
- `customer_id`
- `store_id`

For example,

```
script/generate model SnowboardEvent ev_type:integer snowboard_id:integer \
    customer_id:integer store_id:integer
```

Then I'd set all the relations between `SnowboardEvent`, `Snowboard`, `Customer` and `Store`. Snowboard could have functions like `current_state`, `current_store` implemented as

```
class Snowboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snowboard_events
  validates_presence_of :name

  def initialize(store)
    ev = SnowboardEvent.new(
         {:ev_type => RETURN,
          :store_id => store.id,
          :snowboard_id = id,
          :customer_id => nil})
    ev.save
  end

  def current_state
    ev = snowboard_events.last
    ev.ev_type          
  end

  def current_store
    ev = snowboard_events.last
    if ev.ev_type == RETURN
      return ev.store_id
    end
    nil
  end

  def rent(customer)
    last = snowboard_events.last
    if last.ev_type == RETURN
      ev = SnowboardEvent.new(
           {:ev_type => RENT,
            :snowboard_id => id,
            :customer_id => customer.id
            :store_id => nil })
      ev.save
    end
  end

  def return_to(store)
    last = snowboard_events.last
    if last.ev_type != RETURN
      # Force customer to be same as last one
      ev = SnowboardEvent.new(
           {:ev_type => RETURN,
            :snowboard_id => id,
            :customer_id => last.customer.id
            :store_id => store.id})
      ev.save
    end
  end
end
```

And Customer would have same `has_many :snowboard_events`.

Checking the snowboard or customer history, would be just a matter of looping through the records with `Snowboard.snowboard_events` or `Customer.snowboard_events`. The "temporal data" would be the `created_at` property of those events. I don't think using Observer is necessary or related.

NOTE: the above code is not tested and by no means perfect, but just to get the idea :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer jka! I *almost* set yours as my accepted answer, but EmFi's use of plugins was just so elegant.

Comment: Yes, it seems much more elegant, so might be more what you're looking for. This is probably more basic approach.
Now that I think of it, it wasn't a requirement to be able to return boards to different stores and have the price etc. Well... :)